# How to resize a HTML5 Canvas with JavaScript by clik and drag?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, draggable, resizable

I found a really nice Minesweeper online game ([link](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/mines.html)) and decided to understand a little bit better Canvas and JavaScript relations. One thing that I'm finding interesting is the resizable option this game has. If you click and drag at the bottom right corner of the puzzle, you can resize it. So I decided to investigate its source code to learn more and I learned this:

How to add the canvas to the HTML body and how to link it to a JavaScript file:

```
<div align="center">
<div id="divResizable", style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1000px;">
    <canvas id="myCanvas", style="display:block; border:1px solid #000000;", width = "1000", height = "400">
        HTML5 needed for Canvas to appear
    </canvas>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="expandCanvas.js"></script>
```

How to add the click and drag icon to this canvas with JavaScript:

```
// Creates icon
var resize_handle = document.createElement("canvas");
resize_handle.width = 10;
resize_handle.height = 10;
{
    var ctx = resize_handle.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i += 3) {
        ctx.moveTo(8.5, i + 0.5);
        ctx.lineTo(i + 0.5, 8.5);
    }
    ctx.lineWidth = '1px';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.stroke();
}
// Append icon to div "divResizable"
resizable_div = document.getElementById("divResizable");
resizable_div.appendChild(resize_handle);
resize_handle.style.position = 'absolute';
resize_handle.style.zIndex = 100; // The greater this value, more forward the icon gets ("z coordinate")
resize_handle.style.bottom = "0";
resize_handle.style.right = "0";
resize_handle.style.cursor = "se-resize"; // Changes cursor style
resize_handle.title = "Click and Drag to resize this canvas";
```

Well, after that they combined a compiled C function (using `Module.cwrap()`) with some mouse event listener to handle the resize procedure. ([link](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/mines.js) to their Java Script, starts at line 411). From now on I'm struggling to understand. Even though they use a compiled C function, I believe that HTML/JavaScript might have a simpler solution for that. Doesn't it?

In [this](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/mines.html) puzzle that I'm using as an example, when resizing, it keeps its proportions. I believe that's why it get sophisticated. For me, I'm just curious to learn Canvas and JavaScript. So a simpler solution that just resize the canvas based on the mouse position without the need of keeping its proportions is good enough for me.

What would be a simpler and more standard way of doing that with JavaScript/Canvas?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you just wondering how to make an arbitrary element resizable using JS?

Comment: I was looking for a way to resize a Canvas element by Click-and-Drag (a solution for an arbitrary element might work for the canvas tag). From the puzzle I mentioned, it has at the bottom right corner a click and drag capability (https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/mines.html ).What sophisticates in this case is that it tries to keep its proportions and uses a compiled C code as well. I was looking for a simpler solution standard to JavaScript/Canvas. I'll take a look at this link you sent me. It might help. Tks!

Comment: Since you mention you don't care about proportions, I think the question just reduces to resizing any old element. Canvas is probably not special although there might be special considerations with stretching. Correct me if wrong!

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right. A solution for resizing an arbitrary element migth work for this particular case (canvas). But I'd like to resize by clik and drag. Here an example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEZHIGSPAI5P . If you position your cursor at the bottom rigth corner of the canvas I'd like to be able to clik and drag it and, by doing so, resize it. So yes, it's a resizing an existing element problem but by click and drag (not caring about proportions).

Comment: Considerations with stretching or any proportion like distortions I'll try to handlle latter. For now I'm just concerned with this clik and drag capability.

Comment: Yes yes. I did a cosmetic code to demonstrate what I was looking for. I'll look more tutorials on events handlers. The link you sent me might help. Tks!